# USB/bluetooth tether to Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu

I am trying to provide Internet to laptop, from any of two phones.
I can do it only by wifi, but it drains battery quickly.
When same laptop had Linux Mint 17.1-3 XFCE it worked without problem (on both smartphones).

I am able to connect by bluetooth, and on phone popups message to authorize laptop to use Internet, which I accept, and phone says, that shares connection to 1 device (from this moment Linux Mint had Internet), however, laptop just loops between "retrying connection" and after each 10 seconds "connection failed".
I can send and receive files by bluetooth without problem.

Connecting any phone with usb, and clicking tether as in Mint, makes laptop to recognize connection as "ethernet" (it's okay I guess), but also Internet cannot be accessed.
I can access phone's files by usb without problem, and it gets recognized as right device.

I was trying on both phones with both bluetooth and usb to ping 8.8.8.8 and it gives me "Network unreachable".

Tether by wifi works fine.

How can I tether by usb and bluetooth?

EDIT:
I know, that 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google's DNS, and they will know, which hostnames I want to resolve, if I use their DNS.
However, I have been trying to add 8.8.8.8 as name server in connection settings, and it didn't work - how is this file different?
But yes - adding "nameserver 8.8.8.8" and "nameserver 8.8.4.4" to this file solved issue for bluetooth.
I still cannot tether through usb - lapcop creates "Wired connection 1" with type of "Wired Ethernet", but it cannot really connect to it (last used: "never").
I am unable to force establishing this connection, in connection editor, option "connect" is disabled for this connection, and connection manager in tray doesn't even show it.
I have been trying to remove it, and also add from two separate phones - without luck.

It may be also worth a note, that before adding those nameservers to file, bluetooth couldn't even connect as Network Access Point, but now it works fine.

Remaining questions:
1. How to establish connection through usb?
2. How is nameserver in file different from DNS in connection settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. So try opening /etc/resolve.conf and where nameserver 127.*** change it to 8.8.8.8 then add nameserver 8.8.4.4 save it and reboot. Try your connection again.

Comment: An explanation as to why this works and that this leaks even more of your activity to Google that just using its search engine would be in order

Comment: It solved issue for bluetooth - thanks -  now I am just looking for way to connect with usb